# HDTV settings for videogaming

Tags: ps3, monitor

I just purchased a 55-inch HDTV [VIZIO VF551XVT]. For some reason, when I play the ps3 my TV bothers my eyes. This doesn't happen when I watch the TVs at the store, even if I am really close (normally they are playing movies). So I am not sure if it really is the size of the TV the problem [I am sitting about 2.5 meters away].

could anyone recommend me the settings for my TV when using the PS3?

Comment: It may just be that, although it may not seem like it, you're paying a lot more attention to the game than you would to anything else on the TV.

Comment: Add more details about your connection from PS3 to TV: HDMI, SCART, YUV..?

Comment: Make sure the PS3 is set to run in the best mode the TV supports, hopefully 1080p. Also make sure it is set on Game mode so the extra processing filters that add lag are not used. Check the refresh rate settings (120hz, etc.) and adjust to fit your needs.

Comment: I am using HDMI connection and 240Hz refresh rate.

Comment: Does it bother you when you watch the TV at home?

Comment: That's a good question. It bothers me when I read text on webpages. About movies I don't think it bothers me a lot, or at least, a lot less than playing videogames. I tried all settings now, and I'm sure the ones I've seen at bestbuy didn't harm my eyes at all. I guess I will have to exchange it with a smaller one....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally I wouldnt have thought this would be down to the PS3 or the connection with the PS3 to your new TV.

Generally the display settings (brightness/contrast etc) are set up for the display in stores to give a better emphasis on colours etc which works fine when you are in a store due to their lighting. My opinion would be to search around for best/optimised calibration for your TV through general google searches and it should give you a better picture. Overemphasised brightness/contrast can seriously make a difference when you are using in-home.

Hope this points you in the right direction.